# How can you change the alert text on a pop-up

Tags: 2010, web-part, localization

I am working in the advanced search and am trying to change the message that gets displayed in an alert box (see image below), can anyone help please?

http://content.screencast.com/users/Brendan_Rice/folders/Jing/media/21206e75-4b7f-4036-8a64-cd60890dc564/2011-11-08_1140.png

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this? Is it a 3rd party product? Do you have access to codebehind/front-end files?

Comment: Sorry I should have provided more information. This is sharepoint 2010. It is out of the box functionality (we have just skinned it). There are no code behind/font end files this is default sharepoint behavior.

Comment: I have the same problem here at work, please someone answer. Mine is the message "Cannot be blank" on every field that I'm about to put data in, it's annoying and covering the field that I'm looking at! Please help! Thank you.